# Should we burninate the [stackexchange] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, meta, burninate-request

I didn't notice it until recently, but apparently we have a [stackexchange](/questions/tagged/stackexchange) tag. IMHO it's rather pointless; as you may guess,

> This tag is for questions about the entire network of Q&A sites that make up the Stack Exchange network.

Well, **this entire site** is questions (and answers) about the entire network of Q&A sites that make up the Stack Exchange network. I think we can safely say that if a question can't be tagged with [stackexchange](/questions/tagged/stackexchange) it's off-topic here.

The major problem is that 1.5k questions have this tag, so a manual burninate process will be very cumbersome. There is without a doubt a magic script to remove the tag for all questions (without bumping them), but I can imagine the CMs/devs don't want to run it because it would set a precedent. Still, this might be a case where it's worth it.